# My Sites in SharePoint 2013

Tags: mysite

I am looking for setting up my sites for our users in our organization, but I am so confused:

First I created a my host site collection, will this be shared with all users? How can I create a seperate site for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Following are the main tasks needed to setup My Sites

> - Create a My Site host site collection
> - Add new managed path with wild card inclusion
> - Connect the web application to service applications
> - Enable self-service site creation for the web application Add
> - Permission Policy Level
> - Enable the User Profile Service Application Activity Feed Job

My site host site collection needs to be created only once and you don't need to create My Sites for users. It will be created for them when they click on "Sites" link on top right of the SharePoint page for the first time. 
See these links for more information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx
http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/25/visual-guide-setting-up-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/